# Extracting client specific code. refactoring possibilities required

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I am facing a Design problem. I have a set of classes which writes data in XML,JSON or HTML formates for different clients.

I have a class which receives Data and a XML, JSON or HTML writer as it parameter.

And these Writer have a common Interface, Writer uses the Data to create Data in speficied format. The writes have methods like writeHead, writeBody, WriteImages, writeFooter, writeDescriptions

Now my problem is that Descriptions part of the Documents is very client specific. Only that specific part looks completly different for each client but the rest of the Document is same.

Should I use writeDescriptions as a factory which calls clientSpefic writeDescriptions function? then I have another problem that I have many different formates like JSON,HTML,XML....

What will be the best possible way to hanlde is sitution?

Comment: @kolossus I believe this is existing code that requires some refactoring. Not something that can be done on a white board. This should stay here.

Comment: OP, can you post some of your existing classes to get a better idea about what can be refactored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now my problem is that Descriptions part of the Documents is very client specific. Only that specific part looks completly different for each client but the rest of the Document is same.
>
> Should I use writeDescriptions as a factory which calls clientSpefic writeDescriptions function? then I have another problem that I have many different formates like JSON,HTML,XML....

A factory as you described is a reasonable approach to resolving this problem.  There's no getting around the fact that each client has their own format for the description, so hide that implementation detail behind the `writeDescriptions` method as you described.

Given that you have multiple output formats (JSON, HTML, ...) then you'll need to pass that information along so that `writeDescriptions` can make the appropriate decision.

If possible, consider writing the client specific stuff to a "universal format" and then have `writeDescriptions` make a call to a formatter for the output function (ie. it translates from the "universal format" to the specific output format).  That way you don't have to repeat output functionality across the different client implementations.

---

*Additional thought:* It's possible you may run into a problem using a factory pattern like this, but it's a fairly typical usage.  Don't worry about those future problems until they actually occur.  At that point, you have a new design question to the effect of "I had XYZ problem and solved with a factory.  The factory introduced ABC problem.  How should I resolve?"